# Зависает форма, при использование foreach

Tags: c#, winforms, многопоточность, foreach

зависает форма при использовании цикла foreach. Пробывал вывести в отдельный поток, но результат один и тот же. Форма зависает :(

Код:

```
 private void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {    
      Thread Th = new Thread(Thr);
      Th.Start();          
 }

 void Thr() 
 {
        Action action = () =>
        {
          string link = richTextBox1.Text;
          foreach ()
          {
             //код 
          }
        };
        Invoke(action);
 }
```

Comment: вы создаете отдельный поток, чтобы потом из этого отдельного потока вызвать код в основном UI потоке? Смысл этого? Вы код в основном UI потоке выполняете, вот у вас и зависает UI поток.

Comment: tym32167, а как реализовать тогда все это? 

string value = richTextBox1.Text;
string[] value1 = link.Split();

 foreach (var pair in value1) 
{
//код
richTextBox2.Text += вывод результата;
}

Если мне нужно использовать данные из richTextBox1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пишу без проверки, но принцип должен быть ясен. Всё, что не относится к UI контролам, выполняем в фоне. Что относится - в UI потоке.

```
private async void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // это UI поток
    var text = richTextBox1.Text;
    var result = new StringBuilder();

    // всё, что не касается UI вы полняем в таске
    await Task.Run(() => {
        // это не UI поток, тут нельзя обращаться к контролам UI
        // но result и text - это не UI контролы, 
        // потому их я могу читать/писать
        string[] value1 = text.Split(); 
        foreach (var pair in value1) { result.Append(pair);} 
    });

    // снова UI поток
    richTextBox1.Text = result.ToString();
}
```

Comment: Надо было добавить, что если не ясен - то на so полно аналогичных вопросов про фриз UI потока.

Comment: @AK в смысле отсылать из своего ответа автора искать другой ответ? :)

Comment: Очень хотелось поворчать с утра, что никто не ищет дубликаты )

Comment: @tym32167 У меня куча разного кода, что парится не хочется с этим. Не много сгорел от этого) А как на счет Application.DoEvents(); ? 

Я использовал его в C++\CLR и он отлично работал в цикле. И форма не зависала.
А вот в C# он не работает.

Comment: Вы, конечно, можете и очередь сообщений прокачать этим Application.DoEvents(), но это реально даже не костыль, а инвалидное кресло, которое в текущей задаче абсолютно не требуется @Den2908

Comment: @tym32167, Блин, надо было заранее все продумать, а теперь сижу и думаю)

Comment: @Den2908 а что тут думать, какие проблемы с моим ответом?

Comment: @tym32167, с вашим ответом проблем нету, а вот проблема с кучей мусорного кода в моем проекте))))

Comment: @tym32167, Спасибо что помогали мне! Удачи вам.

Comment: @Den2908 пожалуйста.

Comment: @Den2908 - _Application.DoEvents(); ? Я использовал его в C++\CLR и он отлично работал ... А вот в C# он не работает_ - работа _методов_ фреймворка не зависит от языка, из которого их вызывают. Будь то C#, C++/CLR, VB.Net, F# и прочие. Просто что-то вы делали не так.

Comment: @Alexander Petrov, не знаю, исходный код от предыдущего проекта остался в архиве с паролем, а вот пароль я забыл :) Я бы глянул ради интереса, какую магию я творил.